fparsec f# recursive parser
I have following AST:
type Arithmetic =
    | Add

type IntFunc =
    | MovingAverage

type Formula =
    | SingleParamOp of IntFunc * int * Formula
    | ArithmeticOp of Formula * Arithmetic * Formula
    | Price

and following parsing code:
module Formula =
    let private createParser =
        let pFormula, pFormulaRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Formula, unit> ()

        let pMovingAverage: Parser<Formula, unit> =
            pipe2
                (pLiteral "moving_average" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pInt .>> pComma)
                (pFormula .>> pRightBracket)
                (fun i x -> SingleParamOp(MovingAverage, i, x))

        let pPrice = pstring "price" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pRightBracket |>> (fun _ -> Price)

        let pAdd = pipe2 (pLiteral "add" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pFormula .>> pComma) (pFormula .>> pRightBracket)  (fun l r -> ArithmeticOp(l, Add, r))

        pFormulaRef.Value <-
            choice
                [ pMovingAverage
                  pPrice
                  pAdd]

        pFormula .>> eof

    let parse = createParser

it correctly parses these expressions:
moving_average(3, price())
moving_average(3, moving_average(3, price()))

however, i changed my idea and want expressions to be chained like so:
price().moving_average(3).moving_average(3)
this seems to be much harder to achieve with above parser. I tried:
module Formula =
    let private createParser =
        let pFormula, pFormulaRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Formula, unit> ()

        let pMovingAverage: Parser<Formula, unit> =
            pipe2
                (pFormula .>> pLiteral ".")
                (pLiteral "moving_average" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pInt .>> pRightBracket)
                (fun i x -> SingleParamOp(MovingAverage, x, i))

        let pPrice = pstring "price" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pRightBracket |>> (fun _ -> Price)

        let pAdd =
            pipe2
                (pFormula .>> pLiteral ".")
                (pLiteral "add" >>. pLeftBracket >>. pFormula .>> pRightBracket)
                (fun l r -> ArithmeticOp(l, Add, r))

        pFormulaRef.Value <- choice [ pMovingAverage; pPrice; pAdd ]

        pFormula .>> eof

    let parse = createParser

but then, e.g. this expression:
price.add(price()) results in Exit code is 134

My assumption is that parser goes from left to right, and when i defined individual parsers it's not standard to not start them with identifier (e.g. add/moving_average) as opposed to starting them with formula (so infinite recusion might occur)?
It seems i need to handle recursion myself, but cannot leverage this parser? or am i missing something? It looks like both left and right recursion is a hard problem, or i am overseeing something?

You're right about the recursion, it will indeed generate your error. In fact, it's the (pFormula .>> pLiteral ".") that's the problem, as it will call your parser recursively in a loop.
I'm going to start by assuming (because it's not written in your question) that:
let pLiteral = pstring
let pLeftBracket = pchar '('
let pRightBracket = pchar ')'

Next, to simplify your code, we'll define a simpler parser to handle parentheses:
let parens p = between pLeftBracket pLeftBracket p

Next, we need to deal with your parser problem. As you pointed out, you want to chain parsers, so one way to do this is to consider pMovingAverage and pAdd as parsers that can be chained, i.e. returning a Parser<Formula -> Formula, unit>. We don't do it for Price which (if I understand correctly) is not chainable given your AST. This gives us:
let pMovingAverage: Parser<(Formula -> Formula), unit> =
    pstring "moving_average" >>. parens pint32 |>> fun x i -> SingleParamOp(MovingAverage, x, i)

and
let pAdd: Parser<Formula -> Formula, unit> =
    pstring "add" >>. parens pFormula |>> fun r l -> ArithmeticOp(l, Add, r)

This works because the lambda function expects an additional argument (the second) each time, which will be given later. We therefore need to define a chaining parser that combines the two previous parsers. Given your problem, this will always follow the pattern
"price().[a list of either pMovingAverage or pAdd]"

Therefore,
let pChained: Parser<Formula, unit> =
    pPrice .>>. many (pchar '.' >>. choice [ pMovingAverage; pAdd ])
    |>> fun (state, fs) -> List.fold (fun acc f -> f acc) state fs

The first line is a translation of the pattern identified above, and the second line exploits this pattern to apply the parser to an accumulator (whose first state is simply pPrice).
We can test it out:
let runParser input =
    match runParserOnString Formula.parse () null input with
    | Success(result, _, _) -> printfn "Parsed: %A" result
    | Failure(msg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" msg

runParser "price().add(price())" // Parsed: ArithmeticOp (Price, Add, Price)
runParser "price().moving_average(3).moving_average(3)" // Parsed: SingleParamOp (MovingAverage, 3, SingleParamOp (MovingAverage, 3, Price))

The complete code:
open FParsec

type Arithmetic =
    | Add

type IntFunc =
    | MovingAverage

type Formula =
    | SingleParamOp of IntFunc * int * Formula
    | ArithmeticOp of Formula * Arithmetic * Formula
    | Price

module Formula =

    let private createParser =
        let pFormula, pFormulaRef = createParserForwardedToRef<Formula, unit> ()

        let parens (p: Parser<'a, unit>) =
            between (pchar '(') (pchar ')') p

        let pPrice: Parser<Formula,unit> =
            pstring "price" >>. parens spaces >>% Price

        let pMovingAverage: Parser<(Formula -> Formula), unit> =
            pstring "moving_average" >>. parens pint32 |>> fun x i -> SingleParamOp(MovingAverage, x, i)

        let pAdd: Parser<Formula -> Formula, unit> =
            pstring "add" >>. parens pFormula |>> fun r l -> ArithmeticOp(l, Add, r)

        let pChained: Parser<Formula, unit> =
            pPrice .>>. many (pchar '.' >>. choice [ pMovingAverage; pAdd ])
            |>> fun (state, fs) -> List.fold (fun acc f -> f acc) state fs

        pFormulaRef.Value <- pChained
        pFormula .>> eof

    let parse = createParser

let runParser input =
    match runParserOnString Formula.parse () null input with
    | Success(result, _, _) -> printfn "Parsed: %A" result
    | Failure(msg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" msg

runParser "price().add(price())"
runParser "price().moving_average(3).moving_average(3)"

There are other ways of doing things, and the one I've presented may not be the best or the simplest, but it's what came to mind first (because I've done something quite similar before, but not with parsers).

thank you very much, i think you nailed it. additionally, although i did not specify it explicitely, your suggestion will also parse nested one correctly like -> price().moving_average(3).add(price().moving_average(3)) Have not thought of defining chaned rule like this (was struggling to reason about nested case.

Defining parsers that themselves return functions between parsers to be evaluated later is not something very common and I think it's quite difficult to reason about on larger codes. But it works well here.

@user3530206 When you're satisfied with one of the answers to your question, don't forget to mark it as solved, to make things easier for everyone. Glad I could help anyway :)

If you only need to chain things together at the top level, then FParsec's chainl parser is probably a good bet. Something like this:
type Formula =
    | MovingAverage of int
    | Price
    | Add of Formula

module Formula =

    let pLiteral = pstring
    let pLeftBracket = pchar '('
    let pInt = pint32
    let pRightBracket = pchar ')'

    let private parseOne =
        let pFormula, pFormulaRef =
            createParserForwardedToRef<Formula, unit> ()

        let pMovingAverage: Parser<Formula, unit> =
            pLiteral "moving_average"
                >>. pLeftBracket
                >>. (pInt |>> MovingAverage)
                .>> pRightBracket

        let pPrice =
            pstring "price"
                >>. pLeftBracket
                >>. pRightBracket
                >>% Price

        let pAdd =
            pLiteral "add"
                >>. pLeftBracket
                >>. (pFormula |>> Add)
                .>> pRightBracket

        pFormulaRef.Value <- choice [ pMovingAverage; pPrice; pAdd ]

        pFormula |>> List.singleton

    let private parseDot =
        pLiteral "."
            >>% (@)

    let parse =
        chainl parseOne parseDot []

Testing it out:
runParserOnString Formula.parse () "" "price()"
    |> printfn "%A"   // Success: [Price]

runParserOnString Formula.parse () "" "price().add(price())"
    |> printfn "%A"   // Success: [Price; Add Price]

runParserOnString Formula.parse () "" "price().moving_average(3).moving_average(3)"
    |> printfn "%A"   // Success: [Price; MovingAverage 3; MovingAverage 3]

Note that this won't let you parse nested expressions like price().add(price().add(price()), though.

unfortunately, i would like to nest them as well. Was aware of chaining function, the problem here is exactly this, not nesting.
